# If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor,$ prove that...

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor,$ prove that $f(x)$ has a local minimum at $x=a$. It is given that
> $f(x)$ is a non constant, continuous function.
> Here, $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function.

$$Let \space RHL=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow{0}}f(a+h)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow{0}}\lfloor f(a+h)\rfloor=k, k \in I$$
$$LHL=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow{0}}f(a-h)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow{0}}\lfloor f(a-h)\rfloor =k$$

How to proceed further?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the right and left limits. Let $k$ be the common limit. What would it mean for $f$ not to have a local minimum of $k$ at $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $f$ is supposed to be continuous and $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ takes integer values, $f(a)=\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ is an integer $k \in \mathbb Z$.

If $f$ doesn’t have a minimum at $a$, then it exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converging to $a$ with   $f(a_n) \lt k$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. But then  $\lfloor f(a_n) \rfloor \le k-1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Which implies the contradiction $$f(a)= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lfloor f(a_n)\rfloor \le k-1 \lt k =f(a)$$

Comment: "it exists a sequence..... f(an)<k for all n∈N"  How do you know such a sequence exists and why is the sequence converging?

Comment: If $a$ was not a local minimum, there would be a (deleted) neighborhood of $a$ with a point such that $f(x_0) < f(a)$. Now pick a smaller neighborhood, there still is a point $x_1$ so that $f(x_1) < f(a)$. Continue in this fashion and you can produce a bounded and monotone sequence converging to $a$.

Comment: It is not precise enough both the question and the answer. The question is about the existence of the left and right limit precisely $f(a)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a^-}}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a^+}}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$. Even as simple function as $x$ does not conform, but that is because the mentioned limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ does not exist as left and right limits are different. Once you start from the existence, the case is more or less clear and as stated above.

Comment: @AlexPeter I don't agree. The hypothesis of the question are clear: (1) $f$ is a non constant continuous map and (2) $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$. Your example $f(x)=x$ misses the second hypothesis.

Comment: @fwd it is not about you agreeing, all along you never specify that it is about the existence of the limit itself. $x$ does not belong to this function because the limit of the floor function does not exist, not because it is equal or not equal to anything. That is all. The nature of the limit of the floor function has to be cleared, It is not clear from the answer.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor,$. First line of the question. $f$ is supposed to be continuous, third line of the question, therefore $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{a}}f(x)$ exists and is equal to $f(a)$. $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ takes integer values. Hence, if it has a limit at a point, it is constant around that point. This is trivial. Using the fractional part is useless here.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to clarify the missing point in the accepted answer

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=\lim_{x \to a} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor = f(a) \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\lim_{x \to a} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)-\{f(x)\} = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)-\lim_{x \to a} \{f(x)\}$$

providing that both limits exist.

We know only about $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ so we have that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \{f(x)\}$ must exist too since $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ exists. So

$$\lim_{x \to a} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor=f(a)=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)-\{f(x)\} = f(a) -\lim_{x \to a} \{f(x)\}$$

or

$$\lim_{x \to a} \{f(x)\}=0$$

In general, $f(a) \in \mathbb{Z}$ implies $$\lim_{x \to a} \{f(x)\} \in \{0,1\}$$ providing this limit exists, and we know that it does.

This strictly defines how $\{f(x)\}$ may approach the limit around the same whole number. If it is from bellow, it is $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \{f(x)\} =1$, if it is from above, it is $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \{f(x)\} =0$.

It cannot approach both ways as that would render the limit undefined since we would jump from $0$ to $1$ while we approach $a$. (And this is actually the reason it has the minimum.)

Because of that (that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \{f(x)\} =0$ and that it approaches $0$ from above) there is a vicinity of $a$, $\delta > 0$ for which:

$$ f(a+x) \geq f(a), |x|<\delta$$

This is making $f(a)$ a local minimum.

The key point is:

*$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \{f(x)\}$ cannot approach $0$ both ways, from bellow and from above, as that would render the limit undefined.*

In the same manner

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=\lim_{x \to a} \lceil f(x) \rceil$$

makes $f(a)$ a local maximum.

In both cases, we are just talking only about this specific case that gives a min or a max respectively:

$$\lim_{x \to a} \{f(x)\} \in \{0,1\}$$